# WebStorm: don't fold loops and ifs

Tags: javascript, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, code-folding

[JetBrains Helper](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/code-folding.html) says that:

> Code folding works for the keywords `if/ while/ else/for/ try/ except/finally/` with in case of at least two statements.

[image: Screenshot of code folding]

I would like to fold only functions, like in IDEA etc.

Comment: *To reviewers:* this isn't off topic, it's a question about the _software tools commonly used by programmers_ which [is specifically on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [tag:webstorm] is a sponsored tag for a reason. And it's not too broad, there's probably one or two specific settings that control this behaviour. It also shows some research effort. It may, however, simply not be possible.